# how is config saved in nodeapi_example module?

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

In [this module](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/nodeapi_example!nodeapi_example.module/group/nodeapi_example/7), which hook is responsible for saving the user choice (at `admin/structure/types/manage/<CONTENT_TYPE>`) into the database?

I implemented `nodeapi_example_form_alter()` function exactly as it is, but it is not saving anything.

My hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() in my .module - this does NOT save the value of my radio - anything missing here?

```
function followbtn_form_node_type_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  // First, check for the node type configuration form.
  drupal_set_message('Entered hook_form_alter ...');
  //if ($form_id == 'node_type_form') {
  if (isset ($form['type'])) {
    // Alter the node type's configuration form to add our setting. We don't
    // need to worry about saving this value back to the variable, the form
    // we're altering will do it for us.
    $form['followbtn_rating'] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => t('Custom Rating settings'),
      '#collapsible' => TRUE,
      '#collapsed' => TRUE,
      '#group' => 'additional_settings',
      '#weight' => -1,
    );

    $form['followbtn_rating']['followbtn_node_type'] = array(
      '#type' => 'radios',
      '#title' => t('NodeAPI Example Rating - Custom'),
      '#default_value' => variable_get('followbtn_default_mode_' . $form['#node_type']->type, FALSE),
      '#options' => array(
        FALSE => t('Disabled'),
        TRUE => t('Enabled')
      ),
      '#description' => t('Should this node have a rating attached to it?'),
    );
  }
}
```

I can see the "Enabled" and "Disabled" radio buttons; when I hit "save Content Type", these do not get saved.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no hook that needs to be implemented by the module for that purpose: Saving the value is automatically done by Drupal. In that case, the value for the nodeapi_example_node_type form element is saved in the `nodeapi_example_node_type_<CONTENT_TYPE>` Drupal variable, which is the variable the module accesses for the default value.

```
// Compare the following line...
$form['rating']['nodeapi_example_node_type'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#title' => t('NodeAPI Example Rating'),

  // with the following.
  '#default_value' => variable_get('nodeapi_example_node_type_' . $form['#node_type']->type, FALSE),
  '#options' => array(
    FALSE => t('Disabled'),
    TRUE => t('Enabled'),
  ),
  '#description' => t('Should this node have a rating attached to it?'),
);
```

Similar code is used in [locale_form_node_type_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!locale!locale.module/function/locale_form_node_type_form_alter/7).

```
  if (isset($form['type'])) {
    $form['workflow']['language_content_type'] = array(
      '#type' => 'radios',
      '#title' => t('Multilingual support'),

      // The variabile name is <FORM_ELEMENT_NAME>_<CONTENT_TYPE>.
      '#default_value' => variable_get('language_content_type_' . $form['#node_type']->type, 0),


      '#options' => array(t('Disabled'), t('Enabled')),
      '#description' => t('Enable multilingual support for this content type. If enabled, a language selection field will be added to the editing form, allowing you to select from one of the <a href="!languages">enabled languages</a>. If disabled, new posts are saved with the default language. Existing content will not be affected by changing this option.', array('!languages' => url('admin/config/regional/language'))),
    );
  }
```

As for the purpose of the other node hook implementations:

- [nodeapi_example_node_delete()](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/nodeapi_example!nodeapi_example.module/function/nodeapi_example_node_delete/7) is called when a node is deleted
- [nodeapi_example_node_insert()](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/nodeapi_example!nodeapi_example.module/function/nodeapi_example_node_insert/7) is called when a node is inserted in the database
- [nodeapi_example_node_load()](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/nodeapi_example!nodeapi_example.module/function/nodeapi_example_node_load/7) is called when a node is loaded
- [nodeapi_example_node_update()](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/nodeapi_example!nodeapi_example.module/function/nodeapi_example_node_update/7) is called when a node is updated
- [nodeapi_example_node_validate()](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/nodeapi_example!nodeapi_example.module/function/nodeapi_example_node_validate/7) is called when data entered for a node need to be validated
- [nodeapi_example_node_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/nodeapi_example!nodeapi_example.module/function/nodeapi_example_node_view/7) is called when a node is being show

Notice that `hook_node_update()` and `hook_node_insert()` are mutually exclusive: Drupal calls one or the other, but not both the hooks at the same time. The first is called when an existing node is update; the second is called when a node is created.

In your code the error is the mismatch between the form element name (followbtn_node_type) and the name of the Drupal variable you are using (`followbtn_default_mode_<CONTENT_TYPE>`). You need to change your code in one of the following ways:

```
$form['followbtn_rating']['followbtn_node_type'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#title' => t('NodeAPI Example Rating - Custom'),
  '#default_value' => variable_get('followbtn_node_type_' . $form['#node_type']->type, FALSE),
  '#options' => array(
    FALSE => t('Disabled'),
    TRUE => t('Enabled')
  ),
  '#description' => t('Should this node have a rating attached to it?'),
);
```

```
$form['followbtn_rating']['followbtn_default_mode'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#title' => t('NodeAPI Example Rating - Custom'),
  '#default_value' => variable_get('followbtn_default_mode_' . $form['#node_type']->type, FALSE),
  '#options' => array(
    FALSE => t('Disabled'),
    TRUE => t('Enabled')
  ),
  '#description' => t('Should this node have a rating attached to it?'),
);
```

Comment: I was hoping that Drupal does it too - but would you please mind checking the hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() implementation code i pasted from my module? I see the radio buttons, can select them but cannot save them.

Comment: You are using a name for the Drupal variable that is not `<FORM_ELEMENT_NAME>_<CONTENT_TYPE>`; in fact, the form element name is followbtn_node_type and the Drupal variable name starts with followbtn_default_mode_.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer helped me understand the basics too very much. I will mark it as the answer.